# Direction of Stress

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering

Consider a stress element taken in a prismatic bar acted upon by tensile load only.

[image]

I'm interested in knowing what these arrows represent?

The direction of stress?

But what is direction of stress?

I know that stress is not a vector, it is something more complex (I want to use the word tensor, but I don't completely understand what tensor quantities are), then why we are representing the stress via an arrow like a vector?

Also the second subscript in the stress notation $\sigma _ {xx}$, which is x here, is stated in books as *the axis along which the stress is directed*, which again brings me to the same question **what do we mean by the direction of stress?**

Comment: What you are showing is the "traction" vector which is given by $\mathbf{t} = \boldsymbol{\sigma}\bullet\mathbf{n}$ where $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is the stress and $\mathbf{n}$ is the outward normal vector to the surface.  In components, with respect to a coordinate system aligned with the box, $t_i = \sum_{j=1}^3 \sigma_{ij} n_j$.  In the figure this normal vector has components $(1, 0, 0)$ so you get $t_1 =  \sigma_{11}$.  Equating the '$1$' direction with the '$x$' ​direction, we can also write $t_x = \sigma_{xx}$, which is what you have shown.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the surface of the differential cube is A, then the force of tension pulling out of the surface is

$$F=\sigma_{xx}*A$$

The first x refers to the surface the force is acting, with its normal unit vector aligning with the X-axis.

The second x refers to the axis this force is lying along.

eg, If it was, $ \ \sigma xy$ it would mean it is shear stress acting on the same surface and aligned with the Y-axis. Instead of pulling it acts tangent to the surface.

Comment: So the arrows essentially show the direction of the force F. Can I say that "direction of stress" is kind of a misnomer?

Comment: in a way. stress is a bit unwieldy if you want to calculate operations involving it. at the end you switch to force vector.

Answer (score 2):

Stress (in my view) is a convenience quantity. It is the ratio of the force over  an area. Stress directly cannot be measured the way a force can.

So stress is $F \over A$. This mean that it is Force (which is a vector) over an surface area (which also has a normal vector).

[image]

The direction of the force is something straightforward. However, it is possible to have a forces that have a direction on different surfaces of the infinitesimal cube. I.e in the image above, $\sigma_{32}, \sigma_{22}, \sigma_{12} $ all deal with forces which are parallel to the direction $x_2$, however they are applied to different surfaces.

Furthermore, the forces that are applied on $\sigma_{32}, \sigma_{12}$ are parallel to the surface, while $\sigma_{22}$  is normal to the surface --- making them shear and normal stresses respectively.

Comment: So the arrow which corresponds to $\sigma_{22}$ is showing the direction of the internal resistive force due to which $\sigma_{22}$ exists? Do you think "direction of stress" is a misnomer?

Comment: Yes the direction of the force is parallel to the direction of the stress. However, I'm not sure why you think that its a misnomer.

Comment: I mean, I wanted to know what the arrow in the question was representing, so I got it cleared that it represents the direction of the internal force on which stress is based. When we say direction of stress we actually mean the direction of force it is based on. It occurs to me as a misnomer because stress is not a vector, we can't talk about its direction, or can we? "direction of stress" paints stress as a vector.

Comment: Or is that we can actually associate a direction to stress, and it's the same as the direction of the internal resistive force the stress is based on?

Comment: Scalars are tensors of rank zero, vectors are tensors of rank 1, stress is a tensor of rank 2, (there are also higher order tensors). The way I understand it, is that with each increasing rank increasing number of directions are involved. In the case of stress, one direction is the force and the other the normal to the surface.  I have always felt comfortable with the concept of "direction of stress", so I can't really understand what are you suggesting as an alternative.

Comment: Yes, now, I think there is nothing wrong with 'direction of stress'. I initially thought, because its a tensor it can't have a direction but tensors do have a direction. As you told vectors are rank 1 tensors.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, stress is not a vector, but it is derived from the vector $F$, which is a vector and has a direction. So, in a grid system, the arrow indicates the direction of both the force and the resulting stress are pointing to.

For a 3D element, while a single subscription adequately indicates the direction of the normal stress ($\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z$), but, without the double subscription, it is confusing when addressing the **shear stress** of the plane, and the direction, the shear stress is acting on. See the example graph below.

[image]

Comment: So the direction of stress is defined, and it is the same as the direction of force it is based on.

Comment: Yes. The stress lies in the same direction as the force